# Стиль/тема заголовка QDockWidget

Tags: c++, qt5, themes

Разбираюсь с `QDockWidget`. Столкнулся с непонятной для меня вещью - под MS Windows заголовок окошка в доке отображается всегда одинаково, вне зависимости какая тема оформления в MS Windows установлена. Скриншот ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Два вопроса:**

- Данный элемент является управляющим элементом Windows, или Qt рисует его самостоятельно?
- Как видно на скриншоте, а это из стандартных примеров Qt, размещение заголовка, равно как и самого припаркованного окошка - **ужасное**! Целый набор разных отступов. Особенно заметно слева. Посмотрел код, никаких стилей использовано не было. Каким образом припаркованные окошки разместить красиво/правильно? С учетом сборки и для X11, и для OSX.

Comment: `Qt рисует его самостоятельно` — да. Можно убедиться с помощью *WinSpy*, который не сможет выделить ни один Qt-ный элемент управления, ибо это не Windows-окна.

Comment: @Arhad , а у MS Windows есть схожий элемент управления, в смысле - "родной"?

Comment: В *Common Controls* такого нет. Придётся руками переназначать стили окна при пристыковывании-отстыковывании, плюс обрабатывать `WM_MOUSEMOVE` у DockWidget для отслеживания необходимости отстыковки-пристыковки. Касательно стилей: `WS_DLGFRAME | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`, при пристыковке добавляем `WS_DLGFRAME | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP`.

Comment: При отстыковывании - окошко темы подхватывает. Видимо уже обрабатывается средствами ОС. А вот когда оно в доке .... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯